# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined - ws

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, ws

I am trying to get URL starts with '/rtmp/', and extract the target RTMP URL.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

this is my server.js

```
  let match
  if (!(match = req.url.match(/^\/rtmp\/(.*)$/))) {
    ws.terminate() // No match, reject the connection.
    return
  }
```

Comment: Can you show some more code, like where `req` is coming from?  And, is this with Express still, yeah?

Comment: i fixed that error installing FFmpeg in my Computer